# PHP strtotime last week for every day

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

Hi I have a query that selects from the database where the

```
`timestamp` >= '".$monS."' AND `timestamp` < '".$sunE."'
```

And here is how the `$monS` and `$sunE` is defined:

```
$startTime = "00:00:00";
$endTime = "23:59:59";

$today = date('l', strtotime("now"));

if($today == "Monday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -7 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -1 days $endTime");
}
    if($today == "Tuesday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -8 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -2 days $endTime");
}
if($today == "Wednesday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -9 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -3 days $endTime");
}
if($today == "Thursday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -10 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -4 days $endTime");
}
if($today == "Friday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -11 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -5 days $endTime");
}
if($today == "Saturday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -12 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -6 days $endTime");
}
if($today == "Sunday"){
    $monS = strtotime("yesterday -13 days $startTime");
    $sunE = strtotime("yesterday -7 days $endTime");
}
```

It works however most of the time, the rows it counts can be incorrect for the weekends I think.. well staff on my website say it's not counting Saturday and Sundays properly. Does my script look okay?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to get:

> Find everything in MySQL in the week preceding this past Sunday.

To do that, I would use the current day of the week to find Sunday, and then subtract a week.

```
$dow = date('N'); // current DOW – 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tues...
$now = time();
$sunE = $now - (24 * 3600 * $dow); // 24 * 3600 = one day in seconds
$monS = $sunE - (24 * 3600 * 7);
```

Comment: Is `$sun` meant to be `$sunE` ?